# How to use scroll view in relative layout which exist in fragment?

Tags: android, scrollview

i am stuck how to scroll layout when keyboard appear? this is my static page but when my keyboard appear then my scrollview is not working.i can not give hard code height of scrollview. please help me..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/settingLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/splash_bg" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/tree_iv_userSettings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/tree_transparent" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/image1"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="110dp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/frame_large" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/changepassword"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="CHANGE PASSWORD"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editname"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/changepassword"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="EDIT NAME"
                        android:maxLength="20"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/editphoneno"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editname"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:hint="EDIT PHONE NUMBER"
                        android:maxLength="15"
                        android:numeric="integer"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edittype"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/editphoneno"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="EDIT TYPE"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/notification"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/edittype"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="NOTIFICATION"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/togNot"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/save"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/on_button" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/save"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/notification"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:text="SAVE "
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="40dp" />

                    <ProgressBar
                        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>




Please help me out.
suggestions apreciated
Thanks Kind Regards.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="@drawable/splash_bg" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tree_iv_userSettings"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/tree_transparent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/frame_large" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/changepassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="CHANGE PASSWORD"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/changepassword"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="EDIT NAME"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editphoneno"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="EDIT PHONE NUMBER"
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:numeric="integer"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edittype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editphoneno"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="EDIT TYPE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edittype"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="NOTIFICATION"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/togNot"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/save"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/on_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/notification"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="SAVE "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And add this code to ypur manifest project:

```
 <activity
        android:name="YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|stateAlwaysVisible" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: :- Thnax iman.. i was little bit mistack in my code , i solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add this code in ur manifest activty

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysVisible"
```

Comment: @M S gadag :- i already registered this code in my manifest. and i am working on fragment and this code i applied on my fragment activity.

Comment: i think we can not register fragment on manifest, and i am using fragment under the fragment activity.

Comment: have registered fragment activity rite...add in that

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.treeapp.header.Header"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysVisible"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            
             >
        </activity>         //this is my fragment activity entry  in manifest

Comment: is ur actvity name is Header? where u want to implent scroll on keyboard show?

Answer (score 0):

```
this code useful for scrolling relative layout..

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/settingLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/splash_bg" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/tree_iv_userSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/tree_transparent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/frame_large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/changepassword"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="CHANGE PASSWORD"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/changepassword"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="EDIT NAME"
                android:maxLength="20"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editphoneno"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editname"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="EDIT PHONE NUMBER"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:numeric="integer"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/edittype"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editphoneno"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="EDIT TYPE"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/notification"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/edittype"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="NOTIFICATION"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/togNot"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/save"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/on_button" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/notification"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:text="SAVE "
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="40dp" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image1"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="27dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottomRelay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_margin="7.5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Upload"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Upload Photo"
                android:textColor="#8F8F8F"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Upload"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#939393" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/choose_existing"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/border1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Library"
                android:textColor="#007AFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/choose_existing"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#939393" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Camera"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/border2"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Camera"
                android:textColor="#007AFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/border3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/Camera"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:background="#939393" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/border3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:background="#ededed"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Cancel"
                android:textColor="#007AFF"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```